# How Do I get the Method from a Stripe.JS payment Element

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment

Seems this is lost in the docs, but I do not want to set payment methods for Stripe. Instead, I would like to use the payment element and get back the payment method the customer chose.

I am creating it like this:

```
  if(cardElement.value !== null) {
      stripe = await loadStripe(process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY)
      elements = stripe.elements({clientSecret: paymentIntent.value.client_secret});
      paymentElement = elements.create('payment', {
        classes: {
          base: 'p-4 bg-slate-50 border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm'
        }
      })
      paymentElement.mount('#card-element')
```

And I am retrieving it like using `elements.getElement('payment')`. Seems to work fine, but now I would like to create a payment and for that, I would like to know whether it is a card, sepa, or whatever payment, because I need that futher down the line in the payment process and I do not want to hard-code cards. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you trying to see which "tab" (card vs sepa vs other payment method types) a user has selected when interacting with the Payment Element or are you trying to get which type was used to actually confirm and complete payment after the Payment Intent is successful?

Comment: I would like to know which payment type was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which Payment Method type/tab has been selected on the PaymentElement you can listen for the `change` event (see https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=paymentElement). When you receive the event, the `value` object will say the currently selected Payment method type.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer since it actually exactly answers my question. I found out however, that using a combination of Laravel Cashier (create payment intent) and webhooks (log stuff to the DB) lets me use the recommended features of Stripe more seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive id of payment method used for completing intent payment in web-hook response of stripe:
`req.body.data.object.payment_method`

Then you can get list of all payment methods and filter by id to know more details about used payment method